# How to conditionally make http call in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component with buttons that take actions and modify data bound input properties.

When the component initializes, in `ngOnInit` I want to make an `http get` call and then render the result.

When a user subsequently clicks a button that modifies a few data bound input properties, however, I want to re-render the component/template/view but in that case I don't want to make the `http get` call. I only want to make the `http get` call on first opening the component, or after the form in the component has been submitted.

Conceptually, what I'm aiming for is:

`details.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {

data: Object;

if (certainUserButtonsWereClicked) {
   renderView();
} else {
   makeHttpGetCall.subscribe(data=>{this.data=data;renderView()});
}
```

What condition(s) do I check for to determine the value of `certainUserButtonsWereClicked`? Do I need to use `ngOnChanges` and check the `SimpleChanges` object to see if and/or what type of changes have been made, or is there an easier/better way?

Comment: I think you can simplify tgis if I do not misunderstand your goal. Just add the renderView() in the data=> {this.data = data; renderView();} .. then add a (click)="renderView()" on your html button element.

Comment: when you change the data your component should be dynamically updated if it is using 2 way binding

Comment: When yoi change data, it should automatically reflect on html using angular bindings. Above things we used to with normal jquery or vanila JS when Frameworks for JS was not there. If we use above approach then no use of Angular

Comment: Many thanks. I'm using reactive forms. No two-way binding.

Answer (score 1):

You should try service functionality of angular and get api call using service,and make one click event in html page which bind with componet.ts file and after that click event make api call using service and it's return to the component where you subscribe that api data.
And put that function of component in ngOnInit as this.(function name).
So when you click on button or when open that page always ngOnInit function will call and you get proper data as you want,hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm really confused. The code below doesn't actually work with my Forms because my component doesn't have any data-bound Input properties. I'm not sure if I should "artificially" add data-bound Input properties to trigger ngOnChanges? I'm back to Square One, and will have to resubmit my question. . .

=====

Firstly, apologies for not phrasing my question more clearly. Upon further research, I think the only way to do what I want to do is to use OnChanges, but the good news is this wasn't nearly as involved as I first expected. In fact, it's quite easy. This is how I implemented the code:

`details.component.ts`

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  {
doGet: boolean = true;
data: any[] = [];

 ngOnChanges(chg: SimpleChanges){
    if (chg.doGet.previousValue === false) {

// When user clicks button, "doGet" property is set to false in the (click) event 
// handler. On re-rendering, it's initialized to "true", so we need
// to reference the previous value, and set it back to "false"

   this.doGet = false;  

// We also need to re-set our key data to the updated version of the old data
// rather than re-fetching the data using HTTP GET

   this.data = chg.data.previousValue;  

   }

 }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.doGet) {
      this.member.getDetailsForm(this.userID).subscribe((data)=>{  // Perform HTTP GET
        this.data = data;
        this.renderDataArray();
      })
    } else this.renderDataArray();
```